# c# Перемещение формы, на которую добавлен UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, usercontrol

Всем привет.
У меня есть UserControl (обычный TitleBar). Этот UserControl находится на MainForm (BorderStyle - none). В чём собственно проблема - при клике на этот UserControl, который находится в Форме, она должна перемещаться, как и любая другая форма, которая имеет границы, вместе с этим TitlePanel. Я попытался это реализовать. Ниже код, который находится в UserControl:

```
private const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
private const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;

public void TitlePanel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{ 
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        ReleaseCapture();
        SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
    }
}

[DllImport("user32.DLL", EntryPoint = "ReleaseCapture")]
private extern static void ReleaseCapture();
[DllImport("user32.DLL", EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
```

Но прикол в том, что двигается только собственно сам UserControl, а не форма вместе с ним. Пробовал по-разному гуглить, но как-то всё очень грустно.

Да, конечно, можно всё реализовать тупо в лоб: для каждой формы копировать и вставлять этот TitleBar в каждую форму, все ивенты, переменные настраивать в каждой форме, но это больше похоже на очень некрасивую реализацию или даже костыль. Может можно как-то всё-таки передавать информацию о клике на TitlePanel в основную форму и двигать их вместе?

Comment: А в процессе перемещения можно же менять координаты формы? https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/walkthrough-performing-a-drag-and-drop-operation-in-windows-forms

Comment: Имеете ввиду передавать форму в качестве параметра в ивент?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут winapi вообще не нужен. Указатель захватывается сам во время drag-n-drop'а и с этим ничего делать не надо. Надо просто двигать саму форму в обработчике `MouseMove`.

А чтобы посчитать, что именно двигать, надо подняться наверх по цепочке [`Parent`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.parent?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)ов.

Что-то такое:

```
private Form form;
private int baseLeft;
private int baseTop;

private void TitlePanel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{ 
  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
  {
    for (var x = this.Parent; x != null; x = x.Parent)
    {
      if (x is Form f)
      {
        form = f;
        baseLeft = f.Left - e.X;
        baseTop = f.Top - e.Y;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

private void TitlePanel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  if (form != null)
    form.Location = new Point(baseLeft + e.X, baseTop + e.Y);
}

private void TitlePanel_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    form = null;
}
```

А ещё мне что-то вспоминается, что надо не подписываться на события, а переопределять методы `on*`.